# Default port (8081) changing to different port in jfrog-artifactory-oss-7.3.2 in windows 10

Tags: deployment, repository, port, devops, artifactory

I have installed the jfrog-artifactory-oss-7.3.2 in windows 10. Default port has been changed to the 8285 in below files. (8285 port is available)

1. C:\jfrog-artifactory-oss-7.3.2-windows\artifactory-oss-7.3.2\app\artifactory\tomcat\conf/server.xml
2. C:\jfrog-artifactory-oss-7.3.2-windows\artifactory-oss-7.3.2\app\misc\tomcat/server.xml.template
3. C:\jfrog-artifactory-oss-7.3.2-windows\artifactory-oss-7.3.2\app\misc\tomcat/server.xml

once execute artifactory.bat server is getting up without any issue. I don't see any log errors in catalina log either access, access_service etc log files.

but browser gives below error.

***** HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report
Message /ui/
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/8.5.51 *****

If i change back to the default port(8081) it works perfectly.

If someone came across issue like this please share your thoughts and solutions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To change server port of artifactory, you need change in [system.yaml](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+System+YAML). Please review system.yaml.template.

The path in system.yaml is

```
artifactory:
  port: 8081
```

This change will make changes needed in server.xml as well.

Also if you want to change the router port which serves the UI. Please change  `system.yaml` as below

```
router:
    entrypoints:
        externalPort: <new port>
```

Let me know  if this does not work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I applied the changes (port as 8285) in file called "system.full-template.yaml" in two places.

C:\jfrog-artifactory-oss-7.3.2-windows\artifactory-oss-7.3.2\app\misc\etc

C:\jfrog-artifactory-oss-7.3.2-windows\artifactory-oss-7.3.2\var\etc

but still i am not able to see the jfrog login page.

Comment: My requirement is to change the jfrog artifact default port since 8081 port is already acquired as service of network monitoring in windows server.

Comment: Mahesh,  The file the system reads is  `system.yaml`  in `var/etc/`. You need to add a new file called `system.yaml` and add  the section as  above if this is  the  only customization  you want to do. The  template files  are only for reference, changing the template file will not reflect in the system. Please make sure  the `system.yaml` is ownerd by artifactory user and it  is  able to read and write.

Comment: Thanks for the reply prasanna. It got worked perfectly. I have doubt on the routing port though.

Though it got up and running the port which was configured in system.yaml file i am seeing the browser url as http://localhost:8082/ui/. Why port is always get routed to the 8082 port though it is not the port which is configured in system.yaml. Where i can configure this port and Can i stop routing?

Comment: Mahesh - THere are two ports. One is artifactory port which  is set for artifactory as per above. There is a router port which routes to various other moduels like access, ui, metadata and later xray, mission control etc.  This port is set under router section as below: `router.entrypoints.externalPort` The default for this is 8082. If this answered  your  question, please mark this as the answer, please.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Prasanna.