# Unable to Access Jfrog Artifactory URL

Tags: artifactory

Access **JFrog** Artifactory URL is routing to a different port 8082 different screens. The JFrog Artifactory service has been running on Port 8081 and now all of a sudden, I am not sure of any recent change but accessing it is redirecting to a different port 8082 and presented with a different screen.

[image]

**Additional Info:**

- I do not have **nginx** or reverse proxy configured in the machine. But not sure why the redirection happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you have upgraded Artifactory to a new version which is 7.x. 7.x serves ui over port 8082 while still serving Artifactory APIs over port 8081.  Please refer new architecture [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/System+Architecture)

If you want to change any of these ports refer the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61300397/default-port-8081-changing-to-different-port-in-jfrog-artifactory-oss-7-3-2-in/61300468)

Comment: These instructions no longer work, I guess :latest tag is the 7.x release which breaks existing users. Maybe this could be updated? https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Installing+with+Docker